# Laravel Session return previous value

Tags: laravel

When I write this line of code of my controller

```
public function cartAdd(Request $request){

    $request->session()->put('key', 'value 1');
    $output = $request->session()->get('key');
     dd($output);
}
```

Then output "value 1"

But when I comment one line code which set the session value

```
public function cartAdd(Request $request){

  // $request->session()->put('key', 'value 1');
    $output = $request->session()->get('key');
      dd($output);
}
```

Then output

"this is key 1"

This is my previous session value. What's wrong with this. This time output should be "value 1"

Comment: your code seem's right check may be it is overriding  some where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions.

1. Remove dd() method. Because of dd() request not complete and it's not working.
2. Save the session using $request->session()->save(); .

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your session. Give this a shot:

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value 1');
$request->session()->save();
$output = $request->session()->get('key');
dd($output);
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!